# Always show the navigation arrows on a flipview control in RTXAML

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using a XAML FlipView Control for a Windows 8 store application.

When I use the mouse and the mouse is over the FlipView control the previous/next navigation buttons are shown.

However if I don't use a mouse and use touch, the navigation buttons hide.

I would like navigation buttons to always be visible. How can I do this?

I've looked at the control template but I can't see anything in there that sets the visibility of the navigation buttons.

Ta

Comment: You've exposed the control template, and you see the objects (Probably Paths) acting as the navigation buttons individually? If that's the case there should be a declaration in the `VisualStateManager` toggling the visibility of those objects on the PointerOver state. Is it possible you may have just not gotten deep enough in the template(s)?

Comment: @user1131657: any solution found?

Comment: no, no valid solution yet

Comment: [This answer for a Windows 10 `FlipView` may also apply to Windows 8.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813881/1399567)

Answer (score 2):

Try [dynamically hide/show the buttons](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0ea7eaf4-3f11-4bcb-93f7-b5f6e6a02418/hiding-the-next-and-previous-buttons-of-a-flipview-programatically?forum=winappswithcsharp).

```
private void Show(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonShow(fv, "PreviousButtonHorizontal");
    ButtonShow(fv, "NextButtonHorizontal");
    ButtonShow(fv, "PreviousButtonVertical");
    ButtonShow(fv, "NextButtonVertical");
}
private void Hide(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonHide(fv, "PreviousButtonHorizontal");
    ButtonHide(fv, "NextButtonHorizontal");
    ButtonHide(fv, "PreviousButtonVertical");
    ButtonHide(fv, "NextButtonVertical");
}
private void ButtonHide(FlipView f, string name)
{
    Button b;
    b = FindVisualChild<Button>(f, name);
    b.Opacity = 0.0;
    b.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}
private void ButtonShow(FlipView f, string name)
{
    Button b;
    b = FindVisualChild<Button>(f, name);
    b.Opacity = 1.0;
    b.IsHitTestVisible = true;
}
private childItemType FindVisualChild<childItemType>(DependencyObject obj, string name) where childItemType : FrameworkElement
{
    // Exec
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child is childItemType && ((FrameworkElement)child).Name == name)
            return (childItemType)child;
        else
        {
            childItemType childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItemType>(child, name);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.